# How handle html responses in a Restful Api

Tags: rest, rails-api

I am working on a large api, it tries to be restful (and for most part it succeeds), one of our client requires a term of service in html format.

Is it ok to have a endpoint that returns html in a restful json api? Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's best to have the client dictate the content type via Accept header in the HTTP request. You can default to `application/json` and have the client call the API they require with a `text/html` Accept header.

It is okay for RESTful services to return any media type, as long as the API itself is agnostic of it.